# Why does mongoose use schema when mongodb's benefit is supposed to be that it's schema-less?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a super newbie to mongodb. I am using mongoose to access mongodb from node.js, and know how to get things to work, but I don't think I understand why it works the way it does.

Most importantly, I don't understand why mongoose has 'schema' when one of the standout features of mongodb is that it doesn't have schema. Could someone enlighten me? thank you.

Comment: I think it is a case of a default schema however you can then dynamically add fields within your app code without having to change the table as a whole. An example is a huge table of products, adding a field in SQL to that is nasty and slow, in MongoDB just add it to the client model...

Comment: MongoDB is not schema-less.  It's got flexible schema - there is a big difference.

Comment: it's a matter of taste, Mongoose lets you have a typed schema with validations, if you use the driver you don't get that and will have to roll your own. On the other hand the layer of Mongoose will impact raw performance somewhat as it does a bit of housekeeping that takes additional time over the raw driver.

Comment: I'm working in node/mongodb/mongoose currently but also have deep roots in C#, LINQ and SQL Server. Mongodb does have a schema but its very loosely structured in that its simply objects, arrays and JavaScript types along with some other types like ObjectId, Date etc. forcing you to manage things in code in terms of schema. Mongoose let's you easily define the structure of data along with making the mongodb interaction simple. I've tried just doing mongodb direct and mongoose is just so much more convenient as you don't have to invent your own way to enforce your schema.

Comment: Is weaker performance compared with the raw driver the only negative consequence of Mongoose?  Are there any other pitfalls or gothyas, or is it a tool worth implementing in almost all use cases?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Data without a schema is useless. You get a document from MongoDB, what do you do with it? Read some fields? You need to know the names, types and meanings of those fields. That’s a schema.

When people say that MongoDB “has no schema”, they really mean that it does not enforce schema the way SQL databases do. MongoDB pushes schema concerns up to your application level, where you can handle them more flexibly. For example, in order to add a new field to your documents, you don’t need to do an all-or-nothing `ALTER` on your collection—potentially millions of entries. You just add that field to your ODM (Mongoose) schema and you’re done.

Comment: not entirely true. There are realtime apps that can rely on fields created on the fly. Adding a field to Mongoose model means a new deploy process. There are ODMs that doesn't require a fixed schema definition, Mongorito for instance.

Comment: Ever heard of custom fields?  Say you want your clients to be able to define their own schema, something you'll want to store in its own collection without having to have a developer change code for every customer.  This is a perfect use-case for schemaless design.

Comment: @TimHardy You say “define their own schema”, but then call it “schemaless” — see a contradiction there? I didn’t say “data without a static schema is useless”.

Comment: @TimHardy Would not that be trouble at reading data? Perhaps it needs conditional code on reading to know whether a specific field exists on a particular document or not.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to no static schema as "schemaless".  In my scenario the schema is stored in MongoDb - perhaps it's best to call it a dynamic schema.