# Express js and Mongo DB database definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I started learning node these days and Im using Express js framework.

I found this great tutorial from Christophe Coenraets with all stuff I need since I have a little bit experience in Backbone js.

The thing that's confusing me the most in Node js is working with databases . (I'm only familiar with MYSQL since i was using PHP)

For example in this tutorial , in this file

https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/routes/wines.js

He use "populateDB" function to populate the database for the first time whit some doomy data when app is started,

Now since I was using PHP , I what to do the same thing I was doing there , I want to create database structure or something like shell so I can have an image in my head to to represent the data , for example I saw some example is "mongoose" module "mongo db object modeling" that there are some things like "Schema" or something like that .

Can somebody explain me right logic on working with databases in Node js, how you start when you are creating your app, the process and stuff? its little bit confusing to start working and to dont know from the start how the database will look like.

Tnx a lot ! :)

Comment: It's rather long to explain. I suggest you read up on http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/ and then of you get stuck come back for help.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about NoSQL databases like mongodb is that you no longer have the traditional columns, rows, and tables. We now have fields, documents and collections. See [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

Mongoose is a framework that provides a schema-based solution to modeling your application data. It's not necessary to use but does provide you with the option of having predefined schemas and models similar to that of SQL schemas, instead of inserting straight up JSON into the collections. See [Why does mongoose use schema when mongodb's benefit is supposed to be that it's schema-less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107976/why-does-mongoose-use-schema-when-mongodbs-benefit-is-supposed-to-be-that-its) for more details.

For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var catSchema = new Schema({ //cat schema
  name:  String,
  age: Number
});

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema); //cat model

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian', age: 5 }); //kitty is a cat
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('Error saving to the database');
});
```

...and now you have a kitty saved in your mongodb

So to start: download and install mongod and mongodb, npm install mongoose, create your schema and model via mongoose.

To query/find/retrieve documents/rows from the database, use the model.find(), ex:

```
// named Zildjian and at least 5
Cat.find({ name: 'Zildjian', age: { $gte: 5 }});
```

For more details, please see [model.find API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Comment: Tnx , this helped me a lot !